# Error while NPM INSTALL inside angular project

Tags: angular, node-gyp, node-sass

We are a team working on a angular project. After downloading the code from repo, when I try to run $npm install, im facing the following error.

I have tried installing node-gyp, node-sass, deleted node_modules under project directory but nothing resolves the issue while executing $npm install

> ../src/create_string.cpp: In function ‘char* 
>       create_string(Nan::MaybeLocal)’:
>   ../src/create_string.cpp:17:37: error: no matching function for call to 
>        v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Local&)’
>          v8::String::Utf8Value string(value);
>                                            ^
>
> In file included from /home/pc-username/.node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/node.h:63:0,
>
> ```
>              from ../../../../../nan/nan.h:54,
>              from ../src/create_string.cpp:1:
> /home/pc-username/.node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3002:5: note: candidate: v8::String::Utf8Value::Utf8Value(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>)
>      Utf8Value(Isolate* isolate, Local<v8::Value> obj);
>      ^~~~~~~~~
> ```
>
> /home/pc-username/.node-gyp/12.7.0/include/node/v8.h:3002:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
>   binding.target.mk:127: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o' failed
>
> ```
> make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/create_string.o] Error 1
> make: Leaving directory '/home/pc-username/project-folder/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/node-sass/build'
> gyp ERR! build error 
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/pc-username/project-folder/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
> gyp ERR! System Linux 4.18.0-25-generic
> gyp ERR! command "/usr/lib/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/home/pc-username/project-folder/project-name/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
> gyp ERR! cwd /home/pc-username/project-folder/project-name/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/node-sass
> gyp ERR! node -v v12.7.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
> ```
>
> Build failed with error code: 1
>   npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN angular-font-awesome@3.1.2 requires a peer of font-awesome@^4.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 (node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/node_modules/node-sass):
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
>
> audited 46047 packages in 162.363s
>   found 641 vulnerabilities (1 low, 640 high)
>     `run`npm audit fix`to fix them, or`npm audit`for details`

Can someone point me what the problem is?

Regards,
Ananth S

Answer (score 5):

Face same issues before probably the issue is from node sass.

Try to delete your package.json.lock and run npm install.

Refer to this link: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1991

Comment: I had a similar error ---- int v8::String::WriteUtf8(v8::Isolate *,char *,int,int *,int) const': cannot convert argument 1 from 'char *' to 'v8::Isolate *' ---- but this fix worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if it is of any use for someone having this issue nowadays with the latest versions of angular using Ivy (8+), I was recently struggling with the `package-lock.json` and node-modules (deleting and reinstalling all multiple times, even updating my node and npm versions to the latest as suggested in the previous answer and many other related questions similar to this one), all of those with no success.

What got it fixed was running

```
npm audit fix
```

I think that what happened is that `node-sass` was replaced in favor of `dart-sass` as of Angular version 8
https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/29/angular-cli-8.0/#dart-sass-replaces-node-sass

I noticed in my package-lock.json that no matter how many times I deleted it and retried npm install, `node-sass` was always an `@angular-devkit/build-angular` required dependency (whereas in my newer Angular 10 projects created with angular CLI the dependency was plain `sass`)

After running `npm audit fix`, my `package-lock.json`was updated to use `sass`as required dependency for `@angular-devkit/build-angular`, same as it is by default in the newer Angular projects.

If anyone has more clarity on why this is the way it is or another better way to solve it, I'd be thrilled to know. Otherwise I hope this helps.

I read about the `npm audit fix` solution in another similar question in stack overflow I can't seem to find again right now :(
I will link it if I see it again, but credits to that guy.

Comment: This answer worked for me too, thank you so much, Natalia!
Just make sure you have node version 10 or less, it breaks with version 11 and up.